# Logout of MetaMask with API

Tags: metamask

Is there a way to logout of MetaMask from my own frontend, allowing the user to logout with a button rather going up to the Metamask extension and logging out through the traditional manner?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way. This is by design, for security reasons (no change of address, login, logout, or any other sensitive operation that MetaMask requires the user to do himself).

Comment: A popup could have been implemented asking the user "do you want to disconnect?" in the same way every other action requires user confirmation.

Comment: How is it safer to keep the account that was logged in once logged in forever? I was looking for this feature especially because I don't like my app skipping the "select wallet" screen just because I logged in once 2 months ago

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Moralis** for this.
This is how you would be able to logout through a react or a next frontend:

```
import { useMoralis } from "react-moralis"

export default function Home() {
  const { isAuthenticated, logout } = useMoralis()
  // If you are logged in isAuthenticated is set to true
  return (
    <>
    {isAuthenticated ? 
       (<button onClick={logout}> </button>) 
     : (<div> <!-- Handle you login here --> </div>)}
    </>
  )
}
```

That's just a basic snippet for logout on click of a button. Read the npm docs for more info: [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moralis?activeTab=readme)